# Problem with generating the client using axis2

Tags: apache-axis, soap-client, soa

Configuring the client using the WSDL gives the following exception:

```
axi2 Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/ws/commons/schema/utils/NamespacePrefixList
```

I attempted to resolve this by downloading the jar file "xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar", but the exception persists.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: no one for help?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem by changing the version of:

axis2, from 1.7.X to 1.6.X
Appache Tomcat: from v9.0 to v7.0

and there is no exception